# Add DuckDuckGo to search engines list in Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

I am using a Samsung S3 **Rooted** phone. I want to customise Google Chrome to add DuckDuckGo in the list of search engines, and maybe make it my default one.

It is not possible to do this in chrome by default. I have Googled this question and have not found any way to do this.

Comment: There is a lot of people talking about it online: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2097329 and here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1545359 That should do it. You may need Chrome Beta, but that is in the Play Store anyway.

Comment: Thanks Ross
But Google Chrome on Android seems to be hardcoded.
It adds "search?q=" before the search expression 
So searching for "test" will end into 
https://duckduckgo.com/search?q=test and that will search "search" instead of "test"

Comment: What about in Chrome BETA, NOT THE FULL ONE, changing the settings mentioned in the 2 posts in my first comment? Change from: "last_known_google_url": "http://www.google.com/" "last_prompted_google_url": "http://www.google.com/" To: "last_known_google_url": "https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=" "last_prompted_google_url": "https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=" You cannot do it in Chrome, but the BETA should work fine. I've just watched someone do it and it worked fine on his phone! EDIT: which is an ancient phone and an OLD chrome beta. May not work on newer one I'm afraid.

Comment: Anyone desperate to add DuckDuckGo can try this solution with alternative Chrome-based browser - http://android.stackexchange.com/a/148880/137930

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is now possible in Chrome 57. Just visit DuckDuckGo, perform a search (search for anything), then visit Settings > Search engine and DuckDuckGo should be listed at the bottom of the page.

---

After doing the DuckDuckGo search, if you still don't find DDG on Chrome's *Search Engine* page, you may (as I did, using Chrome 61) have to go to [DuckDuckGo.com](https://duckduckgo.com) and then do the following:

1. Tap DDG's three-line symbol (**≡**) in the upper-right corner of the webpage.
2. Tap ***Other Settings***.
3. Scroll down to the *Install DuckDuckGo* section, and make sure "Show links to instructions . . ." is set to ***On***.
4. Tap ***Save and Exit***.
5. Back on DuckDuckGo.com, tap the ***Add to Chrome*** button if you see it; if you don't see it, scroll down to find the ***Add DuckDuckGo to Chrome*** button, and tap that.
6. A "Take Back Your Privacy!" message should pop up. Follow its instructions:

   1. ) Tap the Google app's three-dot symbol ([image]) in the upper-right corner of the browser window.
   2. ) Tap ***Settings***, then tap ***Search engine***.
   3. ) Now, DuckDuckGo **should** be there at the bottom for you to select; at least, it was for me.

I hope this works for you too!

Comment: Works on unrooted Android (Samsung S6).